# Полезность интерфейсов

Tags: java, c#, c++, ооп, интерфейс

Зачем нужны интерфейсы? Не надо мне объяснять, как их использовать и как они работают, я это знаю. Я не понимаю, какая от них может быть практическая польза? Только создавать лишний файл и писать лишний код, который всё равно переписывать с реализацией внутри классов (все случаи использования интерфейсов в любых "уроках" можно намного проще реализовать без них — они просто занимают место).

Comment: А как вы напишете программу высокого уровня без интерфейсов? Создадите свой собственный язык? И это будет интерфейсом для ваших программ. Не очень понятен ваш вопрос, приведите пример. Вы имеете ввиду интерфейсные классы?

Comment: Причём тут свой язык? Я не понимаю, зачем писать лишний код, если можно просто вызвать конкретный метод сразу у объекта класса, или, если метод статический, у самого класса.

Comment: я отметил ваш вопрос как дубликат, поглдяите на оригинальный вопрос, там было несколко ответов.

Comment: Если не понимаете, то вам это не нужно. А так, суть интерфейсов в абстракции. Это удобно, когда реализация класс висит например не на вас, ваш класс должен к примеру вызвать метод `Send()` и все, а как этот метод будет реализован, ему знать совершенно не нужно, это пусть делает например другой отдел/человек. Вот допустим вы пишете бота, который должен сохранить данные, куда сохранить - решать не вам, вы делаете интерфейс с методами, которые должен реализовать тот, кто будет это использовать, вам опять же, не важна реализация, нужно лишь вызвать метод. Для таких целей и существуют интерфейсы.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду интерфейсные классы(не файлы), то  вам уже указали где прочитать ответ, хотя я сказал бы проще: Интерфейсные классы  очень удобный механизм, например, для написании  общего кода(алгоритма), независимо от того  объекты какого  типа  будут участвовать  ,    таким образом обеспечивая модульность.

Comment: @tym32167, а вы зря закрыли вопрос как дубликат. С чего вы решили, что кто то не даст ответ лучше, чем в том вопросе? Это же чисто теоретический вопрос, а не вопрос как написать класс или как передать в функцию...

Comment: Я прочитал, но так и не понял, зачем. Весь второй ответ снова свёлся к попытке объяснить, как они работают. Первый же ответ совершенно упускает из виду то, что я так же могу написать методы в классе сохранения и просто оставить их пустыми, чтобы потом доделать. И зачем он создаёт эти пустые методы в абстрактном классе? Это же ничем не отличается от интерфейса, просто помимо этого загромождает возможность наследования, при этом оставаясь всё таким же бесполезным куском пустого кода.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так вы всегда можете пойти в тот вопрос и дать там свой ответ. Я закрыл как дубликат из за того, что этот вопрос спрашивает то же самое, что тот вопрос.

Comment: `я так же могу написать методы в классе сохранения и просто оставить их пустыми, чтобы потом доделать` про это не написано, так как класс с пустыми методами != интерфейс. Это абсолютно разные вещи.

Comment: @tym32167,  я вас понимаю,  я то могу( в данный момент нет времени), но если кто то другой позже ответит там, то автор вопроса  скорее всего не узнает об этом, и этот ответ для него не будет существовать.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan точно также и в обратную сторону, если кто то ответит тут, то автор того вопроса не узнает об этом. Суть дубликатов в том, что если кто то будет искать ответ на такой же вопрос, то этот кто то найдет все ответы в одном месте, вместо того, чтобы заходить в каждый дубликат и читать ответы по отдельности. + отметка дубликатом дает понять всем остальным, что на вопрос уже есть ответ, чтобы люди не постили одинаковые ответы. Теперь,чтобы дать третий ответ там (в оригинале), автору ответа надо будет написать что то такое, чего ещё нет там в существующих ответах, что делает ответы лучше.

Comment: уговорили, не против

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я могу мониторить тот вопрос.

Comment: В таких языках как c++, c# и java интерфейсы помогают решить такую проблему, как *определение типа* и частично решая проблему контракта вызова функций некоторого объекта, который наследует это интерфейс.